# How to stop installation if older version of software installed in windows?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, installshield

I am facing a problem while packaging my latest software version in windows 7.My latest version of software is **not compatible for upgrade**.So if a user already have old version of software , i have to stop the installation (disable next button in the installation windows)or give some notification to Customer to remove the older version.
Is it possible this in install shield(2015)?

Comment: In MSIs this is done by checking the `UpgradeCode` and then comparing the version number. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pusu/archive/2009/06/10/understanding-msi.aspx - as InstalShield is built on top of MSI the same concepts should apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to follow the same mechanism as `ISPreventDowngrade` uses. In the Upgrades view, there is a major upgrade item configured as Detect Only. Then in the Custom Action and Sequences view, there is an error action that only fires if the action property of that upgrade item is set.

If you duplicate both of those items with a new action property (and thus new condition), and change the upgrade item to find your earlier version range instead of future versions, you should be able to get the behavior you want.

If you expect there's a specific threshold of versions (i.e. upgrading from anything 1.0-4.0 to anything 5.0 or later requires this, but upgrading from 5.0 to 6.0 will not), you can configure the version range explicitly. If instead you expect you will always need this in the future, you can search for any previous version and let the upper range match your product. Either can be changed for any release in the future.